# Struts has detected an unhandled exception

Tags: java, hibernate

I am working on a project which is used hibernate and struts both. It worked fine till I opened eclipse last time. When I opened eclipse which is the IDE of my project, all projects were gone from project explorer window. They were in the workspace but they were erased from project explorer window. Then I realized my apache tomcat server is crashed. So I reinstalled it and imported some of my projects to eclipse again. But this project I am talking about right now, shows an error and I can't figure out what that is.

[image]

These errors only show up in jsp files and that error only show up in the top of the jsp file as shown below.

[image]

This index.jsp file runs fine though. But when I clicked reg.jsp file link in index.jsp I get following error.

```
Struts Problem Report

Struts has detected an unhandled exception:
Messages:   

    Communications link failure due to underlying exception: ** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** java.net.ConnectException MESSAGE: Connection refused: connect STACKTRACE: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538) at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:434) at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:244) at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:271) at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2771) at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.(Connection.java:1555) at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285) at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664) at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208) at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:193) at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292) at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297) at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169) at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67) at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160) at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1395) at com.im.medic.db.DB.list(DB.java:38) at com.im.medic.action.MemberAction.execute(MemberAction.java:42) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252) at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265) at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:139) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54) at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562) at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77) at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516) at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ** END NESTED EXCEPTION ** Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
Could not open connection

File:   com/mysql/jdbc/Connection.java
Line number:    2,847

Stacktraces
    org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection

org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:131)
org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:304)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169)
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1395)
com.im.medic.db.DB.list(DB.java:38)
com.im.medic.action.MemberAction.execute(MemberAction.java:42)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:139)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The link to reg.jsp file has been added using struts.

```
<li><a href="member" class="link"><b>SIGN UP</b></a></li>
```

Please tell me how to fix this problem.

Comment: This looks like your build path is set incorrectly. Have you checked to make sure your build path is set correctly in eclipse and you have all the appropriate libraries?

Comment: Yse. I have added them correctly.